# Geom Line of four different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot four different variables in one graph. My data looks something like this:

| Team | Date | Total | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 2020-02 | 50 | Old |
| Red | 2020-02 | 20 | New |
| Green | 2020-02 | 30 | Old |
| Green | 2020-02 | 40 | New |

The x-axis would be the date and the y-axis the total. The teams would be differentiated by color, while data would be differentiated by line type.  Running the code below gives me this error message "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous."

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Total)) + geom_line(aes(color = Team, linetype=Data))
```

Comment: Are u sure the x axis should be the Date? What kind of plot do you want?

Comment: Yup, something like the third plot here https://rkabacoff.github.io/datavis/Multivariate.html but with lines instead of points

Comment: Do you have more data? Now you only have one observation per line so could you please share more data?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure whether you are looking for this answer:

```
df<-read.table(text = "Team Date    Total   Data
Red 2020-02 50  Old
Red 2020-02 20  New
Green   2020-02 30  Old
Green   2020-02 40  New",header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=as.numeric(Total),
                 color=Team,
                 linetype=Data))+
  xlab(df$Date)
```

[image]